# Could a Person with "Bug" Controlling Powers Realistically Make Spider-Silk Armor?

Tags: internal-consistency, super-powers

Say there's a person who can control every kind of "bug," (For the purposes of this post, the definition of "bug" includes any arachnids, myriapods, insects, and worms that exists in the world) with their mind in a 2-mile radius with no limits as to how many "bugs" they can control at any given time. They can give a command to any "bug" they want, and the "bugs" have to follow it, even if the "bugs" or the "bug" controller leaves the two-mile radius, and can only stop if they complete the orders or if the controller tells them to stop. This person often gives their "bugs" tasks to complete as they leave for their job as a fashion designer.

What I want to know is if there would be anything hindering this person from making some kind of spider-silk armor or clothes. I had been thinking about having the controller order their "bugs" to weave up a suit like a Disney princess talking to their animal friends, maybe use some of the hardier "bugs" exoskeletons for plating and reinforced with even more silk, but I'm not sure if I'm missing anything. Would the person need any secondary powers for their main power to work as described above? Any materials or knowledge they might not have, even with their job? Or just use their powers in a different way to what I'm describing to achieve a similar goal?

Comment: Spider silk armor already exists and spiders are not insects.

Comment: Spiders are not insects. They don't care about your hero's insect-controlling powers. (The most recent common ancestor of spiders and insects lived about 500 million years ago. For comparison, the most recent common ancestor of humans and sparrows lived about 300 million years ago.)

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Let me change some things.

Comment: There's a web serial called 'Worm', which has a creep-crawly controlling MC who makes spider-silk armor, and in fact goes into great detail about it, so I'd recommend reading that. It's definitely not as strong as the web serial makes it out to be, but it's a good starting point I guess.

Comment: I see. I will give this story a look when I get the change. Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't even need to extend it to spiders. Humans already get silk from insects, specifically silkworms.

Comment: do you want the insect manually create the silk armor/clothing or human hand or worker is included? silk armor or clothing did exist especially wear by asian, for spider silk, modern armor did have it for their kevlar type suit, but iam not sure for the latter can be made manually by the spider itself iam not sure the former can be done by silkworm or spider too since iam not knowledgeable about it but the possible chance is higher at least.

Comment: oh yeah now that i think about it, if it manually made by spider or silkworm wont it still be sticky? is it fine to you? since as far as i know regarding silkworm process they need to fry or boil it to loosen the silk.

Comment: I'm starting to think that a human hand should be used to help make the armor/clothing, just to make it easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

If you can control *every* insect within a two mile radius, and you add in arachnids into the equation, then you can make spider silk 'armor'. If the MC is a fashion designer by day, then they shouldn't even need to have the insects do anything so complex as to make 3D shapes - just the spider silk would be fine and then said designer could turn it into armor. (Though you'd need to layer the silk on top of itself for maximum effect.) This would also give the MC a chance to do other things with said armor, like apply it to *actual* armor. Spider silk armor isn't that good. Sure, it's bulletproof, but it's also kind of elastic, which means that if you just wear the spider-silk, then the bullets will leave little dents in whoever's wearing the armor. Better than being shot clean through, I suppose, but Kevlar is still better.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "complex 3D Shapes," what are you referring too?

Comment: The shape that normal body armor is in. If you want the entire thing to be in one piece of spider-silk, then you need to instruct the spiders to weave that whole shape. It's a lot easier to just make squares of silk cloth and use those.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you'd want to go to that much trouble, but in theory yes, so long as you are able to specify the garment in great detail (spiders have little experience in the garment field).

You'd end up with something similar to a Kevlar (or similar) vest you can buy of the internet, which is not exactly a superpower. You will definitely need ceramic plates if people are firing serious bullets at you, and you still have problems if they shoot you in the face.

It might be a lot more effective to use all those swarms of insects as a form of protection, A living reactive smokescreen blotting out anyone who tries to take aim at you.  Also -- murder hornet, anyone? That might be defensively useful in the right place.